# How to use an Excel cell value as a variable in a SELECT statement in Power Query?

Tags: sql, excel, powerquery

I am getting some data from a SQL server and by doing so I would like to retrieve data only after a certain date. The date is stored in a cell in an Excel workbook. This is what the code looks like:

```
let
Source = Sql.Database(SERVER, DATABASE, [Query="select  
PET.TransDate, PET.ProjId, DirParty.name, PET.EmplId, sum(PET.Qty) as TOTH from ProjEmplTrans as PET#(lf)  
inner join emplTable as EMP on EMP .EmplId = PET.EmplId#(lf)  
inner join dirpartyTable as DirParty on DirParty.PartyId = EMP .PartyId#(lf)  
inner join  projTable as Proj on Proj.ProjId = PET.ProjId#(lf) 
where PET.TransDate < '01.01.2020' and proj.cnlActive=1
group by PET.ProjId, PET.EmplId#(lf), DirParty.name, PET.TransDate"])
in
Source
```

So far the date is put hard in the code but I want to get it from the Excel cell.

I try this:

```
Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Start_date"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]
```

Where 'start_date' is the named cell where is the date

This is the error I get:

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database(SERVER, DATABASE, [Query="select  
    PET.TransDate, PET.ProjId, DirParty.name, PET.EmplId, sum(PET.Qty) as TOTH from ProjEmplTrans as PET#(lf)  
    inner join emplTable as EMP on EMP .EmplId = PET.EmplId#(lf)  
    inner join dirpartyTable as DirParty on DirParty.PartyId = EMP .PartyId#(lf)  
    inner join  projTable as Proj on Proj.ProjId = PET.ProjId#(lf) 
    where PET.TransDate < Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Start_date"]}[Content]{0}[Column1] and proj.cnlActive=1
    group by PET.ProjId, PET.EmplId#(lf), DirParty.name, PET.TransDate"])
in
Source
```

Token Comma Expected.

I have no idea if it's the way to do it.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to concatenate that function to your query, you need to do it like this:

```
    Source = Sql.Database(server, database, [Query="select  
 ...
    where PET.TransDate < " & Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Start_date"]}[Content]{0}[Column1] & " and proj.cnlActive=1
    group by PET.ProjId, PET.EmplId#(lf), DirParty.name, PET.TransDate"])
in
Source
```

Answer (score 0):

It almost did the trick, and this is how i manage to make it work:

```
Source = Sql.Database(server, database, [Query="select  
 ...
    where PET.TransDate < ' " & Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Start_date"]}[Content]{0}[Column1] & " ' and proj.cnlActive=1
    group by PET.ProjId, PET.EmplId#(lf), DirParty.name, PET.TransDate"])
in
Source
```

I add ' before and after the calling of the cell and it ok

Thank you

Comment: Oops, I forgot that. Glad I could help.